# 0 results returned with mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a graph which takes data from one of our databases and counts the number of issues we had for each of the last 12 months. The query is running fine but it keeps returning 0 results even though there is records in the database that match the query. The code i am using is as follows...

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['dept'])) {
    $dept = $_POST['dept'];

} else {

    $dept = '';

}


for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $months[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date('Y-m-01') . " -$i months"));

}

foreach ($months as $month => $value) {

    $theMonth = date("M", strtotime($value));
    $theYear  = date("Y", strtotime($value));

    $sql = "SELECT `c_ID`, `department`, `departmentSub`,  `todaysDate`, \n" . "SUM(CASE WHEN department='$dept' AND  departmentSub LIKE 'Loading Error' AND MONTH(todaysDate) = MONTH($value) AND YEAR(todaysDate) = YEAR($value) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS loadingErrors,\n" . "SUM(CASE WHEN department='$dept' AND  departmentSub LIKE 'Bad Customer Service' AND MONTH(todaysDate) = MONTH($value) AND YEAR(todaysDate) = YEAR($value) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS custService\n" . "FROM `nonConformance`";


    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        // Return the number of rows in result set
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $loadingErrors = $row['loadingErrors'];
            $custService   = $row['custService'];
        }

    }
}
?>
```

I cant figure out why this is not returning any results, can anyone help me out with this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[example data]https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UQQB.jpg

Comment: did u run this on php myadmin?

Comment: Even if the query is working, `$loadingErrors  = $row['loadingErrors'];` you assigning every time the `$loadingErrors` to the `$row['loadingErorrs']` . That means `$loadingErrors` and `$custService` will have the last month's data. Try using `print_r($results);` to see if query worked.

Comment: I have tried to run it in php my admin and it also runs fine on that but returns no results. I have also tried to run the same conditions on a basic select query which also returns 0 results.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos this is what i want to do - it runs in a loop and counts outputs the loading errors for each month
if ($month >= 11){
   echo  $theMonth;
  }
  if ($month < 11){
   echo  $theMonth.", Loading Errors: " . $loadingErrors . " Customer Service: " . $custService. " | ";
  }

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: And where exactly are you printing these results?

Comment: I think the `$sql` statement is wrong. Try first doing something like `$sql = "SELECT c_id FROM nonConformance"` . If that works then you will have to rebuild your sql query

Comment: why are you having line breaks inside the query?

Comment: @olimortimer 581734498a28b  2016-10-31 12:08:41  2016-10-30 12:00:00  Internal  Warehouse  Loading Error

Comment: the line breaks are just to make it easier on the eye for each separate part of the query

Comment: Can u try with this `$sql = "SELECT `c_ID`, ` department `, ` departmentSub `,  ` todaysDate `,SUM(CASE WHEN department='".$dept."' AND  departmentSub LIKE '%Loading Error%' AND MONTH(todaysDate) = MONTH($value) AND YEAR(todaysDate) = YEAR($value) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS loadingErrors,SUM(CASE WHEN department='".$dept."' AND  departmentSub LIKE '%Bad Customer Service%' AND MONTH(todaysDate) = MONTH($value) AND YEAR(todaysDate) = YEAR($value) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS custService FROM ` nonConformance `";`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks for the suggestion, have just tried that and it is exactly the same result

Comment: @AKAust even on phpMyAdmin you not getting anything?

Comment: This may be a code for testing purposes but have in mind that it's absolutely vulnerable for sql-injections if you don't sanitize your POST-Vars!

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes its the same in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @FelixGeenen yes i do normally sanitize the post variables im just trying to get the basics working at the min

Comment: well @AKAust if this does not return any data with phpMyadmin that means the query conditions are not met

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i have just posted a link at the bottom of the post to show some example data which should be picked up by the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you're not passing through `$value` as a string.  Try surrounding `$value` with apostrophes:

```
 $sql = "SELECT `c_ID`, `department`, `departmentSub`,  `todaysDate`, \n" . "SUM(CASE WHEN department='$dept' AND  departmentSub LIKE 'Loading Error' AND MONTH(todaysDate) = MONTH('$value') AND YEAR(todaysDate) = YEAR('$value') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS loadingErrors,\n" . "SUM(CASE WHEN department='$dept' AND  departmentSub LIKE 'Bad Customer Service' AND MONTH(todaysDate) = MONTH('$value') AND YEAR(todaysDate) = YEAR('$value') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS custService\n" . "FROM `nonConformance`";
```

`MONTH($value)` becomes `MONTH('$value')` and `YEAR($value)` becomes `YEAR('$value')`

Also, make sure you're outputting the values of `$loadingErrors` and `$custService` within the `foreach ($months as $month => $value) {` loop, otherwise dates that have zero values will overwrite the previous.

Comment: Thank you all for your input on this problem you have saved my day :)

Comment: No problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your query?

Replace

```
    departmentSub LIKE 'Loading Error'
```

with

```
    departmentSub = 'Loading Error'
```

or

```
    departmentSub LIKE '%Loading Error%'
```

If your looking for an exact string value, why use LIKE?

Comment: I have tried all three of those already, but thanks for your answer!